# How to set ContentControl.Range to the current ContentControl I am working from?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, word-contentcontrol

I am not finding a way  to set the `ContentControl.Range.Text` from where the C# is executing from (inside the content control). Perhaps I should be looking at it from a completely different perspective.

Currently I have a content control that produces a set of text with some text between [] square brackets and I want to select text and format the colour by setting the start and end of the range of characters between the []. I am stuck on trying to set the initial range to the contentcontrol I am currently using.

Most of what I have managed/found/patched together below.

```
object word;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document _PWdDoc;

try
{
    word = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
    //If there is a running Word instance, it gets saved into the word variable
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //If there is no running instance, it creates a new one
    Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Word.Application");
    word = System.Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application oWord = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application) word;
_PWdDoc = oWord.ActiveDocument;

System.Collections.IEnumerator ContentX = _PWdDoc.ContentControls.GetEnumerator();
//Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ContentControl ContentX = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ContentControls.Item[]; 
//Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ContentControl.Range.Duplicate(ref ContentX);

//var rngX = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ContentControl.Range(ContentX);
//Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ContentControl cc1 = ContentX;
```

Excuse the coding mess but it's all I can come up with with the minimal experience I have with this.

Now I have gotten the IEnumerator fo the Content Control(I think) I have no idea how to use it besides from what I have read, they say to iterate through the IEnumerables accessing each of them. That's not what I want to do. I want 1 content control. The current one that I am working in. I want to find it's range and assign it to a value. Then in that range's "text" I want to do some [**fancy**] highlighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Determining whether the current selection or a specific `Range` is in a content control and doing something with that content control is not a trivial matter. Most other Word objects will return something that they're "in"; content controls do not.

So the approach I use is to

- create a `Range` that reaches from the current selection (or a specific `Range`) back to the beginning of the document
- count the number of content controls in that range
- then check whether the current selection is in the same range as the last content control of the extended range.
- if it is, then I know the selection is within a content control and I can access the content control.

Here's some sample code. The snippet that calls the function I use to return the information:

```
        Word.Range rng = null;
        //Substitute a specific Range object if working with a Range, rather than a Selection
        Word.ContentControl cc = IsSelectionInCC(wdApp.Selection.Range);

        if ( cc != null)
        {
            rng = cc.Range;
            rng.HighlightColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdYellow;
        }
```

The function:

```
    private Word.ContentControl IsSelectionInCC(Word.Range sel)
    {
        Word.Range rng = sel.Range;
        Word.Document doc = (Word.Document) rng.Parent;
        rng.Start = doc.Content.Start;
        int nrCC = rng.ContentControls.Count;
        Word.ContentControl cc = null;
        bool InCC = false;

        rng.Start = doc.Content.Start;

        if (nrCC > 0)
        {
            if (sel.InRange(doc.ContentControls[nrCC].Range))
            {
                InCC = true; //Debug.Print ("Sel in cc")
                cc = doc.ContentControls[nrCC];
            }
            else
            {
                sel.MoveEnd(Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, 1);
                if (sel.Text == null)
                {
                    //Debug.Print ("Sel at end of cc")
                    InCC = true;
                    cc = doc.ContentControls[nrCC];
                }
            }
        }
        return cc;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Cindy, Yokki for the prompt responses! I have not had a moment to try it out as of yet but will feedback with my results.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean that the insertion point is inside a Content Control, and your Word Application object is called oWord, then you can get the range of that content control using e.g.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range r = oWord.Selection.Range.ParentContentControl.Range
```

If you have nested controls You can verify that the insertion point is in a Content Control (Word 2013 and later, I think) by checking the value of inCC as follows:

```
Boolean inCC = (Boolean)oWord.Selection.Information[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdInformation.wdInContentControl]
```

However, when dealing with content controls, be aware that *selecting a content control* in the UI is different from selecting the "range of the content control". Programmatically, it's obvious how to select the Range - not so obvious how to select the control. If you select the Range, the ParentContentControl should be the control whose range you've selected. If you (or the user) selected the control, OTTOMH I am not so sure.

Comment: FWIW If Cindy Meister had posted when I started composing my post, I wouldn't have continued. Probably better to ignore mine.

Comment: Actually, I can't believe I hadn't discovered `Selection.Range.ParentContentControl`, so I'm glad you did continue!

Comment: @CindyMeister I'm going to make a guess that you did discover ParentContentControl when Content Controls first came along, but perhaps couldn't make it do what you wanted. Maybe you found a way that worked anyway. I'll have a little look around and see if I can find any opportunities for improving either the question or the answer. Then I'll delete my comments.